# tibco BW http reciever not triggering with get method and with request parameters

Tags: tibco, businessworks

In TIBCO BusinessWorks, in a stater process with a HTTP Receiver process starter:

1. If I configure **no** request parameters in the receiver, then I'm able to receive the request.
2. If I configure request parameters in the receiver, then I'm **not** able to receive the request.

How do I receive the request with request parameters?

I am using TIBCO BusinessWorks 5.9

Comment: Please provide sample URLs that you are requesting

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems incorrect to me. Please check that you have created HTTP receiver parameters what you have in your request url (Your request url should be in following format: http://localhost:portNumber/?Parameter1&Paramter2). There are twon ways to read the parameters: Query string and paramters.

Please let me know if you are able to resolve the issue